# Did the USS Olympia go forward in time?

Tags: star-trek, time-travel, star-trek-ds9

DS9 "The Sound of her Voice":

> LISA [OC]: My name's Lisa Cusak. **Until a couple of days ago**, I was the
>   commanding officer of the Olympia.
>
> SISKO: **The Olympia.**
>
> LISA [OC]: **We left the Federation over eight years ago for a long
>   range exploration of the Beta Quadrant.**
>
> SISKO: What happened to your ship, Captain?
>
> LISA [OC]: **We were finally heading home, if you can believe that,
>   then we picked up some strange energy readings in a nearby star
>   system, and I decided to stop and investigate. We found an energy
>   barrier around the fourth planet that was unlike anything we'd ever
>   seen, and when we probed it with our scanners it triggered a quantum
>   reaction. There was an enormous surge of metrion radiation that
>   disabled our engines. The next thing I knew, we were spiraling in
>   toward the surface. I gave the order to abandon ship and the last
>   thing I remember is a console exploding in my face. I woke up in an
>   escape pod on the surface and I've spent the last day and a half
>   sitting in this cave trying to raise someone on subspace.**
>
> BASHIR: Captain, Doctor Bashir, Chief Medical Officer. Your message
>   said that you were on a L class planet. Are you sure?
>
> LISA [OC]: Positive. And to answer your next question, yes, I've been
>   giving myself fifteen cc's of triox every four hours to compensate for
>   the excess carbon dioxide in the atmosphere. Just like it says in my
>   medical tricorder.
>
> BASHIR: How much triox do you have left?
>
> LISA [OC]: One hundred and fifty millilitres.
>
> BASHIR: Will you to decrease the dosage, Captain, to eight cc's every
>   six hours. We need to stretch your supply as long as possible.
>
> KASIDY: What happens when she runs out of the drug?
>
> LISA [OC]: That's a good question, Doctor. What happens then?
>
> BASHIR: You will begin to experience the effects of hypoxia. But
>   before that happens, the triox compound will have strengthened your
>   cardiopulmonary system, allowing you to better withstand the effects.
>
> LISA [OC]: Better withstand the effects. In other words, I'm going to
>   be gasping for air and turning different shades of blue by the time
>   you get here.
>
> BASHIR: Yes, I'm afraid so.
>
> LISA [OC]: Thanks for brightening my day.
>
> KASIDY: Is there anything we can do?
>
> LISA [OC]: There is, actually. I can't sleep. I think the injections
>   are keeping me awake and **I haven't had anyone to talk to for two
>   days.**
>
> SISKO: We'll be able to help you with that, Captain. I'll have one of
>   my officers stay on the comm. line with you at all times.

So the ship left eight years ago, they were doing long range exploration, Lisa doesn't know anything about the Dominion war, and she's only been on the planet for two days.

We learn later that the crew are communicating with her in the past, which is an entirely different issue.

Did the ship go forward in time when it hit the metreon radiation in the atmosphere? Is that the explanation that Lisa was giving? I'm confused about the time frame of how this all happened.

Answer (score 7):

The Metreon radiation caused a temporal lensing effect, sending her communications into her future (the Defiant's present), and their replies back in time (from their perspective) to Captain Cusak's present. There’s no indication that Cusak’s ship travelled in time; just the communications to and from it.

Dr. Bashir confirmed she had died 3 years and two months prior to them arriving at the planet in the Rutharian sector. So she would have left on her mission 8 years plus 3 years ago, making that 2363 (the episode takes place in 2374).

To put that into perspective, 2363 is one year prior to the first season of Star Trek: The Next Generation

Comment: I understood what happened with the communications which I stated in my question. I also stated in my question that that was not my question. My question was specifically if the ship itself did some kind of time warp, jump, temporal whatever, when it entered the atmosphere. Maybe you could address this one point which is the crux of my question.

Comment: My apologies, No the ship itself didn't travel in time as evidenced by the fact she was dead for 3 years upon the crews arrival. With the dates stated on the show and memory alpha there isn't any room for the Olympia to jump forward in time.

Answer (score 2):

It's not made explicitly clear in [the episode](http://www.st-minutiae.com/academy/literature329/549.txt) but there doesn't seem to be any special reason to assume that the USS Olympia has traveled through time.

When the crew travel through the same barrier there's no obvious time-shift and O'Brien states that the radiation in the barrier is mucking about with the subspace signal

> **O'BRIEN:** *It must have something to do with the energy barrier. When her          subspace radio signal passed            through the metrion radiation in            the barrier, **the signal was           somehow... time-shifted into the            future.***

No doubt when the crew return home, they'll report that the ship was lost three years ago.

Comment: So their communications shifted in time, (which I didn't even bother asking the question how that made any sense at all) but nothing else did? What's unique about a subspace signal but no other energy or matter shifted into the future?

Comment: Dunno. O'Brien handwaves it away and Sisko doesn't seem to want to investigate

Comment: @JMFB: Well, for a start, it goes through subspace...